# Java - Zipping existing files

Tags: java, zip, append, truezip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Appending files to a zip file with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223434/appending-files-to-a-zip-file-with-java)

Hello Java Developers,

Here's the scenario:
Say I have a textfile named `sample.txt`. What I actually want to do is to put the `sample.txt` file into a `*.zip` file named `TextFiles.zip`.
Here's  what I have learned so far.

```
try{
    File f = new File(compProperty.getZIP_OUTPUT_PATH());
    zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("sample.txt");
    zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
    zipOut.closeEntry();
    zipOut.close();
    System.out.println("Done");

} catch ( Exception e ){
    // My catch block
}
```

My code so far creates a `*.zip` file and insert the `sample.txt` file.
My question is how would I be able to insert an existing file to the created `*.zip` file?
If your answer has anything to do with [TrueZIP](http://truezip.java.net/6/index.html), please post an SSCCE.
I have done the following:

- Googled
- Search for existing question. ( Found few. No answer. Some didn't answer my particular question.
- Read [TrueZip](http://truezip.java.net/6/index.html). Yet, I couldn't understand a thing. ( Please do understand )

Comment: A rare question that doesn't need editing!

Comment: By append, do you mean inserting another file into the zip?  What would your zip look like when it's working the way you want?

Comment: 1- You example scares me, as you are not actually coping any data to the zip file, just preparing an index. 2- Zip doesn't have a concept of "append".  Append is normally achieved by copying the contents of the existing Zip file to a new Zip file, adding in the new content, deleting the old Zip file and renaming the new one back into its place. You can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164889/java-library-to-manipulate-jar-files/12167217#12167217) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064676/appending-zip-archive-debugging/12065042#12065042) for some examples

Comment: @Daniel Kaplan Yes, sort of. The *.zip would contain the sample.txt file. However, I want the sample.txt file created through a text editor rather than creating the file by constructing a ZipEntry. As how I learned it, please correct me if I'm wrong, you create and populate the entries through ZipEntry before inserting into a ZipOutputStream.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks MadProgrammer. As usual, professional reply. I have edited the question and changed the append to insert.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the inbuilt Java API.  This will add a file to a Zip File, this will replace any existing Zip files that may exist, creating a new Zip file.

```
public class TestZip02 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      zip(new File("TextFiles.zip"), new File("sample.txt"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void zip(File zip, File file) throws IOException {
    ZipOutputStream zos = null;
    try {
      String name = file.getName();
      zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zip));

      ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(name);
      zos.putNextEntry(entry);

      FileInputStream fis = null;
      try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = fis.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {
          zos.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        zos.flush();
      } finally {
        try {
          fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
      }
      zos.closeEntry();

      zos.flush();
    } finally {
      try {
        zos.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! As expected from you. Thank you! This is what exactly I was looking for.

Comment: This actually answered my question. However, for my learning, what do the try block under FileInputStream fis = null; does?

Comment: Basic a Zip is split into 2 sections, entries and data.  Entries describe the data blocks, including where to find them, so, once your added an entry, it opens a block for you to write to.  The secion you are talking about basically uses a `FileInputStream` to read the file contents and pass it through the `ZipOutputStream` which will compress the file contents and add it to the data block of the current entry.  Once done, I `flush` the `ZipOutputStream` (because I'm paranoid) and close of the entry.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can get  answer for your question: http://truezip.schlichtherle.de/2011/07/26/appending-to-zip-files/

Comment: Thanks! This was a great link. I'll take a look on this.

Comment: +1 but remember that it is good practice to provide most relevant part of link in answer, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Please read [answer].

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, according to [the epic JDK reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), you could use a `while zis.getNextEntry() != null` loop to loop through the file (where zis is a ZipInputStream), then use `zis.read()` to read into an array, which is sent to an ArrayList or similar.

Then, one could use `toArray()`, ["cast" it to a `byte` array with this method](http://randomtype.ca/blog/how-to-cast-object-arrays-in-java/) and `zos.write()` it into the output ZIP file (where zos is a `ZipOutputStream`), using `zos.putNextEntry()` to make new entries. (You will need to save the ZipEntry and get its name with `ze.getName()`, with `ze` being a `ZipEntry`.)You should replace `T` with `Byte` and `byte` (use `byte` everywhere but the `for` loop body) and may need to modify the casting code to use `Byte.byteValue()` to convert from `Byte` (wrapper class) to `byte` (primitive type), like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    convertedObjects[i] = (Byte)objects[i].byteValue();
}
```

Note that this is untested and based on the JDK (entries `ZipInputStream`, `ZipOutputStream`, `ArrayList`, and `Byte`) and a Google search on array casting.

Sorry if that was a bit dense, and hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi MathSquared, thanks for answering. Anyway, what do you mean by replacing T with Byte? I can't seem to understand what T means

Comment: In the method for array casting I linked to, it has `T` in the code. You will need to type `byte` in place of `T` (except in the `for` loop, where you should use the fragment I provided in my answer).