# Zipping two files together in android

Tags: java, android

I want to zip two different files with different file extensions, together into one file. one file ext is **.txt** and other one is **.amr**. My zip file end up having a size 0KB XXXXXX.zip and when I extract it, it gives me a message that said file is corrupt or damaged.

I zip two different file types, Maybe that met be the case to have 0KB.

Any one with a better way of zipping files together?

Comment: So far i tried to check with same file extension and it works, but when I zip different file extensions, it returns a 0kb file.

Comment: Follow http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html and if still see an issue then post the stack trace here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found examples from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-files-in-zip-format/) and from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350629/java-zipping-existing-files). They used “java.util.zip” library and they are straightforward

Comment: that should be a comment or flag as duplicate

Comment: Thanks with you examples

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I use in my apps to make zip files... Just put files into an array and execute the `makeZip` method statically.

import java.util.zip.*

```
public class Zipper {

    /**
     * Creates a zip file from a File array <br>
     *  <br>
     * @param files to add to zipFile.
     * @param zipFile file zip to create.
     * @return compressed zip file.
     * 
     * @throws IOException in case of error.
     */
    private static synchronized File makeZip(File[] files, File zipFile) 
    {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile.getAbsolutePath());
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

            for (File fileEntry : files) {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileEntry);
                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileEntry.getName());
                zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) 
                {
                    zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
                }

                zos.closeEntry();
                fis.close();

                // delete already compressed files 
                fileEntry.delete();
            }
            zos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // catch exception
        }

        return zipFile;
    }
}
```

Use (if you put method in class `Zipper`):

```
File[] files = new File[2];
files[0] = new File("path/to/file.amr");
files[1] = new File("path/toother/file.txt");

File zipfile = Zipper.makefile(files, new File("destiny/of/file.zip"));
```

Comment: Glad to hear @JayStar , I still can't understand downvote, I didn't erase the answer because i'm sure code works. It's part of a library to manipulate zip's i've created  for one of my projects and it's working great so far... :)

Comment: It also worked for me, I don't know what the downvote what was it for. I got help form your source which seems to be working good.