# Copy folder into jar

Tags: java, jar, copy, directory

I am making a modification installer and everything works but I can't figure out how to copy a folder into a JarFile, the folder needs to go into a folder inside the jar. This is my failed atempt. :(

My code:

```
 public class DisplayContent extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    public DisplayContent() {
        handleGraphics();
    }
    public String chosenDir = null;
    private void handleGraphics() {
        setLayout(null);
        JLabel paneTitle = new JLabel();
        paneTitle.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 20));
        paneTitle.setBounds(55, 6, 330, 62);
        paneTitle.setBackground(new Color(237, 237, 237));
        paneTitle.setText("The Halo Ultimate Mod Installer");
        add(paneTitle);

        JButton btnInstall = new JButton("Click Me To Install The Halo Ultimate Mod");
        btnInstall.setBounds(16, 139, 414, 47);
        btnInstall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                install(chosenDir);
            }
        });
        add(btnInstall);

        final JButton forgeFolder = new JButton("Select Forge Jar File! Important!");
        forgeFolder.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                chosenDir = getSelectedDir(forgeFolder);
            }
        });
        forgeFolder.setBounds(16, 80, 414, 47);
        add(forgeFolder);
    }

    public void install(String dir) {
        String jar = dir + "/assets/";
        String absolutePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
        String halo = absolutePath + "/mods";

        try {
            copyFile(halo, jar);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.print(" --- NEW DIR2 --- " + absolutePath);
        System.out.print(" --- NEW DIR --- " + chosenDir);
    }

  public String getSelectedDir(Component parent){
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY );

        if( fc.showOpenDialog( parent ) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION )
        {
            return fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        }

        return null;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}

  public void copyFile(String filenameoriginal, String filenamecopy)throws IOException{
      File destFile = new File(filenamecopy);
      if (!destFile.exists()) {
          destFile.createNewFile();
      }

      FileChannel fileSource = new FileInputStream(filenameoriginal).getChannel();
      FileChannel destination = new FileOutputStream(filenamecopy).getChannel();
      destination.transferFrom(fileSource, 0, fileSource.size());

      System.out.println("Success.");
      if (fileSource != null) {
          fileSource.close();
      }
      if (destination != null) {
          destination.close();
      }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't...

The long answer is, you can, but it's not easy.

Basically, what you need to do is create a new `JarFile`, copy the contents from the first (original) Jar to it, without closing or finalizing the new `JarFile`, add your new content to it.

Once your done (and have closed/finalized the new `JarFile`), delete the old one and move the new one into its place

The following examples may prove to be useful...

- [Creating Folders in a Zip Folder in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381281/creating-folders-in-a-zip-folder-in-java/16381391#16381391)
- [Appending zip archive debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064676/appending-zip-archive-debugging/12065042#12065042)
- [Java library to manipulate jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164889/java-library-to-manipulate-jar-files/12167217#12167217)
- [Compressing and Decompressing Data Using Java APIs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html)

Remember, a Jar file is simply a Zip with some additions ;)

Comment: So i would have to copy the first jars contents onto a folder, then add my content and turn the folder into a jar. ok, thanks

Comment: You can do it all in one swipe - ie, no need to extract the first Jar, copy, re-jar...just unJar and Jar in one process...

Comment: Yes, `JarFile`, there's an entire API written around it.  Basically, for each `JarEntry` in the original, you want to create an exact copy in the destination, then pipe the `JarInputSteam` from the original (entry) to the destination's (JarEntry) `JarOutputStream`.  Once that's done, you simply want to add your folder to it...in similar fashion...